# ng-show and $scope.$apply issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-show

On the HTML I have an overlay div to show a loading progress which uses the directive `ng-show="showLoading"`. On the template `ng-click` I call the controller `searchRequest` method. This method updates `showLoading` to true just before making the http request.

If I do it this way the loading doesn't show, if I use the `$scope.$apply` to update the variable then I got the `$apply already in progress` error message. What is going on? How should I do this?

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js" ></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/searchController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-init="showLoading = false">
    <div id="overlay" ng-show="showLoading">
        <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-spinner.gif" />
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The template:

```
<div ng-controller="searchController as searchController">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Movie Searcher</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Title</span>
        <input style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;" type="text" ng-model="searchController.searchString" required>
    </label>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="searchController.search()">Search</button>

    {{response}}
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
this.searchRequest = function(url) {
$scope.showLoading = true;

$http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    $scope.showLoading = false;
    //console.log("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    $scope.response = JSON.stringify(data);
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var movie = data[i];
        //console.log("Movie: " + movie);
        var genres = '';
        for (j=0; j<movie.genres.length; j++) {
            genres += movie.genres[j];
            if (j < movie.genres.length - 1) {
                genres += ', ';
            }
        }

        console.log("Title:  " + movie.title);
        console.log("Plot:   " + movie.simplePlot);
        console.log("genres: " + genres);
    }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.showLoading = false;
    $scope.response = "Error: " + status;
})};
```

Comment: I don't see a `search` method on the controller, nor is there any mention of `$scope.$apply`. I'd recommend you to minimize the relevant code bits and pieces and put it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so people (and even yourself) have a good chance at playing around with it and figuring out what's going on in your code.

Comment: search method just creates the url and call searchRequest method, I tried to put only relevant code and messed it up :-P Anyway, how to put this on a jsfiddle? I have 2 js, 1 for the routing and another is this controller, could I just paste both in the JS box in jsfiddle?

Comment: If you are looking for generic overlay, and want to avoid maintaing the showLoading property on every ajax calls, there is a good implementation (atleast to start with) from Dan Wahlin using http interceptors. Check it out.. https://github.com/DanWahlin/AngularOverlay/blob/master/app/directives/wcAngularOverlay.js

Comment: Thanks @PSL that's awesome :-) Do you know is there is any easy way to exclude certain requests? I am thinking that maybe on some requests I won't want to block the UI with the overlay.

Comment: Yes you could pass a config property say `{background:true}` while making http call and look for the property in the interceptor, (in case of request it will be the `config.background`, response or error it will be the `response.config.background`) if it is present do not show the overlay. In get call config is second argument, in post call it is the third argument, and soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Overlay div does not have the data context of the right controller.

When you specify the ng-controller directive, you are telling angular to use that specific controller as its current scope.

```
<div ng-controller="searchController as searchController">
```

Whereas for your body section here, you did not specify the right controller. So, angular doesn't know where showloading property is coming from.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-init="showLoading = false">
    <div id="overlay" ng-show="showLoading">
        <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-spinner.gif" />
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
```

Either move the overlay div into the div which has the controller as context or try using $rootScope instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice explanation and advice. Using $rootScope did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to force a digest cycle without having to worry about the phase is to wrap the var change call inside a $timeout function:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.showLoading = true;
}, 0);
$http.get(url).success(function(data) {
...
```

Of course, don't forget to inject $timeout as a dependency in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, already tried that but didn't work because as @Krishna said it was all about the controller scope

Comment: Fair enough. For some reason I understood it works otherwise, just not when that http call follows.